# Drawable on simple button

Tags: android

1. How can a button (Button) receive a drawable and center it on the button without the text?
2. If you can not do this, how then do to the background does not "stretch" button at all?

The problem is that for some button have icon and text, for others only the icon and the third type only text!  So I have to use an object alone, more stylish, rather than several different classes.

Google needs to improve this architecture!  If I want a button with or without text, occluding the center with the image, it is my problem, I should be able to do!

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout, such as [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html), or [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) with a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) to create your custom clickable layout and views.  Also check this article about [layout reuse](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).

Comment: Dear. I need combination: text + image, only image or only text in one same object. ImageButton haven't setText. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your first request: use ImageButton if you wanna have Both, text and drawable, or combinations of that I think you have to subclass button yourself. You can look inside the code of TabWidget how to do that (because TabWidget can already have both but was intended to start Activities)